# Alamofire using optional value with dictionary parameter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

By Apple's definition of dictionary values, since a key may or may not exist any value returned from a dictionary will be optional

> You can also use subscript syntax to retrieve a value from the
>   dictionary for a particular key. Because it is possible to request a
>   key for which no value exists, a dictionary's subscript returns an
>   optional value of the dictionary's value type. If the dictionary
>   contains a value for the requested key, the subscript returns an
>   optional value containing the existing value for that key.

I am trying to make a networking call with an auth_token in my parameters dictionary.

```
let params = ["auth_token" : authToken()]
print(params["auth_token"]) // shows Optional(dwadhuiwahd)
```

The value in the dictionary is not an optional. I check this with conditional binding in the authToken() function and by printing it out. However when printing out the dictionary key that holds the auth_token it shows up as:

```
Optional(dawudhawhd)
```

And this is causing my networking request to fail.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        (response) in
//this fails
}
```

Unless I hardcode the url.

```
let urlString = "https://staging.travelwithterra.com/api/v1/users/" + agentID + "/agent_info?auth_token=" + authToken()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        (response) in //this doesnt fail }
```

My question is, how come Alamofire doesnt take this into account? OR what am I doing wrong, its killing me!

********solution**********

DONT USE .JSON ENCODING! .URL ENCODING!!!

Comment: Well, what's the definition of `urlString`?

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add an exclamation mark. As seen below.

```
print(params["auth_token"]!) // doesn't show Optional(dwadhuiwahd) :P
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work either. The problem was the encoding was set to .JSON not .URL